# Any way to get Currency Names List and map them to Currency Symbols?

Tags: c#, currency, cultureinfo, culture

I have C# code which can generate a list like this, using Cultures ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373800/3-digit-currency-code-to-currency-symbol)):

```
AUD $ 
CAD $ 
EUR € 
GBP £ 
JPY ¥ 
USD $
```

What I want is a list like this too:

```
Australian Dollar
Canadian Dollar
Euro
British Pound
Japanese Yen
United States Dollar
```

What I actually want is that there should be a drop-down style Winforms Combobox, from which the user selects the currency, such as `British Pound`, and then through a function or something, `GBP` or `£` gets returned. This will help me parse the currency value the user might type in the adjacent currency value text box.

So can I use Cultures (or something else which does not require an Internet connection) to get a descriptive Currency Names list ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the full .NET Framework,* you can fetch the unique currencies by enumerating through the `CultureInfo` instances and creating the related `RegionInfo` by `LCID`. You can then return the relevant currency fields from `RegionInfo`, namely, `ISOCurrencySymbol`, `CurrencyEnglishName`, and `CurrencySymbol`.

For example, the following code will return the distinct `ISOCurrencySymbol` along with the associated name and symbol.

```
var currencies = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
    .Select(ci => ci.LCID).Distinct()
    .Select(id => new RegionInfo(id))
    .GroupBy(r => r.ISOCurrencySymbol)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .Select(r => new
    {
        r.ISOCurrencySymbol,
        r.CurrencyEnglishName,
        r.CurrencySymbol,
    });
```

For the ISO Symbols provided in the original question, the following information would be returned:

> AUD, $, Australian Dollar
>   CAD, $, Canadian Dollar
>   EUR, ?, Euro
>   GBP, £, British Pound
>   JPY, ¥, Japanese Yen
>   USD, $, US Dollar

---

Note: `RegionInfo.CurrencyNativeName` also exists, but it will provide the currency name in the native language of the given region. Thus, the same `ISOCurrencySymbol` may have various instances of `CurrencyNativeName` associated with it and would not prove useful for mapping in this scenario.

* .NET Core does not appear to support enumerating `CultureInfo`.

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 now supports enumerating CultureInfo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44434430/77779

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way to accomplish this would be to create a wrapper class for the Currency, something like this:

```
public class Currency
{
   public string Code { get; set; }  // USD
   public string Name { get; set; }  // United States Dollar
   public string Symbol { get; set; } // $
}
```

You can create a collection of these classes and set `Name` as a member to display in your combobox. After the user selects some value, you can easily use Linq for instance to get the correspondent class.