# What is the equivalent of CultureInfo.GetCultures is .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Straight forward question really, What is the equivalent of `CultureInfo.GetCultures` is .NET Core?

Just trying to find a way to enumerate available cultures.

Just to clarify, this isn't the same as `GetCultureInfo` as that only gets a specified culture, (i.e. does not enumerate it)

Comment: That only gets a specific culture, doesn't enumerate it

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Overlooked that one.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you read through this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1669

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/commit/9834a277280f53afc88f1c17110ff2fd7ea8e802 and https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/6 may be of use

Comment: @mjwills These all seem to handle ASP.NET-Core

Comment: My apologies @JanesAbouCleih

Comment: And Microsoft.Extensions.Globalization also can only work with a list of pre-defined supported locales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a good way to enumerate all supported cultures in .NET Core < 2.0. In .NET Core 2.0 the respective queries to the underlying localisation systems have been implemented for windows and *nix, making this API available.

Comment: Thought this might be the case