# Get list of currency code using CultureInfo

Tags: c#

I want to pass the list of all currency symbols to property in c# so instead of manualy giving list of of currency code is there any way to get the available list of currency code or currency symbols using CultureInfo.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: yes but i didnt got anything to get the list of currency code using cultureInfo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373800/3-digit-currency-code-to-currency-symbol (can be found by searching for title - https://www.bing.com/search?q=Get+list+of+currency+code+using+CultureInfo) provides all inforamtion you need.

Answer (score 6):

Note that this may not be completely possible, because a given machine may not have all cultures installed.

That being said, you can load cultures using the [GetCultures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
```

Adding in a little bit of LINQ to provide a selection...

```
// string[] rather than char[] due to NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol returning a string
string[] currencySymbols = 
    CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)

        // This will select the currency symbol for each given Culture
        // Because cultures define a host of number formatting rules, you have to dig into the NumberFormat property to get Currency Symbol
        .Select(culture => culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol)

        // Since some cultures use the same currency symbol, this will trim out duplicates
        .Distinct()

        // Enumerate this to an array in order to avoid reevaluating the entire process every time it's accessed
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: @Steve so it is, I've corrected my code accordingly

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think you just linked back to this question, please double check your links

Comment: Sorry about that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373800/3-digit-currency-code-to-currency-symbol