# string to char in c#

Tags: c#, string, char

i have a class where i am assigning currency variable as follows:

example currency formats USD,EUR etc etc

```
public class codes{
  public char currency{get;set;}
}
```

so i have another class that calls codes to assign it into the currency variable as follows:

```
public async Task<Codes> ExecuteAsync(hCommand command){
Codes c = new Codes();
//i do some coding to get the currency back then i assign it as follows from a string
 c.currency = Convert.ToChar(currency);
}
```

but it throws an error at that line `System.FormatException: 'String must be exactly one character long.'` and the output is returned as `"currency": "\u0000"`

how can i get it to be a char(3)

Comment: You should use `string` instead of `char`

Comment: why not this: ```public string currency { get; set; }```? since you want value like *USD* or *EUR*

Comment: no i cant use it as a string which it currently is because the requested end point requires it as a char character

Comment: Where is that `currency` variable comming from? What is it set to? Why is it a string, if you plan to assign it to a char? Why not use a Enumeration?

Comment: You can also try to convert currency code like USD into currency symbol, it's explained here [3 Digit currency code to currency symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373800/3-digit-currency-code-to-currency-symbol)

Comment: C# does not have `char(3)` as you call it. You can use `string`, or you can create your own type `Currency` that holds a string which is assured to have the right format (like, not too long).

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your class like

```cs
public class Сodes
{
    public string Сurrency { get; set; }
}
```

and use in the following way

```cs
Codes c = new Codes();
c.Сurrency = currency;
```

[`String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8) in C# represents a readonly sequence of `char` elements, you can't assign string like `"USD"` to a single character.

Another option is to use a `char` array for that, like

```cs
public class Сodes
{
    public char[] Сurrency { get; set; }
}
```

and use [`ToCharArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.8) to assign a value

```cs
Codes c = new Codes();
c.Сurrency = currency.ToCharArray();
```

It's a good rule to use a *PascalCase* for classes and properties names (btw, you `codes` class declaration doesn't match the usage example `Codes`).

You can also refer to this question [3 Digit currency code to currency symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373800/3-digit-currency-code-to-currency-symbol), if want to convert currency code to currency symbol, like `$`

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to store something like a currency, "USD" for example, string is the correct type to do so, not char. Char stores a **single** character.

In any case, if you still want to use char, you should, for this particular case, use an array of chars:

```
public class codes{
    public char[] currency { get; set; }
}
```

And then use ToCharArray instead:

```
c.currency = Convert.ToCharArray();
```