# How to get currency symbol for thailand using RegionInfo

Tags: c#

at the moment I am using region info to get currency symbol.

For other countries it seems to work fine

```
var info= new RegionInfo("THB");
var currency = info.CurrencySymbol;
```

currency ends up being `THB` instead of `฿`

May I ask how do I get the correct currency symbol or why it's returning THB instead of `฿`

I've tried what others suggested, putting "TH", same outcome unfortunately.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373800/3-digit-currency-code-to-currency-symbol

Comment: `var currency = new RegionInfo("TH").CurrencySymbol;` `THB` is not the region but the `ISOCurrencySymbol`.

Comment: can you please add screen shot also without the debug pane, I wonder if you are doing something different because that code works on me.

Comment: @curiousBoy uploaded. Nothing else extra is done :s

Comment: @Master - I am pretty sure that is due to some region settings.

Answer (score 2):

`RegionInfo` get the `Name` in it. And the name for Thailand is "`TH`". "`THB`" is the `ISOCurrencySymbol`

This should work:

```
var info= new RegionInfo("TH");    
var currency = info.CurrencySymbol;
```

[image]

If still not working, check your region settings on your machine to make sure you are not overwriting anything.
[image].

Comment: Maybe I should of tagged xamarin, maybe it's diff on phones?

Comment: can you also try with String.Format("{0:C}", info.CurrencySymbol) ?