# Formatted string contains GBP instead of pound symbol

Tags: c#, .net

Please take a look at the following line of code:

```
TotalFormatted = totalExpenses.ToString("C3", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))
```

I am expecting this to output a number as a formatted string with the pound symbol (£1,500) but instead it is outputting GBP1,500

How can I ensure it outputs the actual symbol instead of GBP?

Comment: I get £ in .net7 dotnetfiddle. And Roslyn, and 4.7.2 and .netcore3.1

Comment: what is the culture in your computer?

Comment: It's based on the culture settings on the local system. If you (or your IT department) has customized this at any time, it will be different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3 Digit currency code to currency symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373800/3-digit-currency-code-to-currency-symbol)

Comment: I am also in .Net 7, I found another solution online which I have posted as my answer

Comment: You can change the symbol to your liking: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WBcLyd

Answer (score -2):

I settled for the following which correctly formats the string with the pound symbol:

```
TotalFormatted = totalExpenses.ToString("\u00A3#,##0.00", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))
```

Comment: This way I can do `var ss = "£"
+ 20.33m.ToString("#.00", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));` or even  `var ss = "£"
+ 20.33m.ToString("#.00")`

Comment: @T.S. Thanks, your way looks cleaner therefore I will use your suggestion

Comment: Why not simply change the currency symbol of the culture: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WBcLyd